# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000000 at problem2.main(problem2.java:17)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I get the following error and I don't know why. I tried looking it up, but I didn't find a solution.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000000 at problem2.main(problem2.java:17)

Here is my code:

```
//Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms.
//By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
//1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
//By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, 
//find the sum of the even-valued terms.

public class problem2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []a = new int[1000000];
        a[0] = 1;
        a[1] = 2;
        int sum=0;

        int i=2;
        while(a[i]<=4000000){
            a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
            i++;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            sum = sum + a[j];
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("\nThere are " + i + " numbers in the sequence.\n");
        System.out.println("This are all the numbers in the sequence:");

        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(j+1==i){
                System.out.print(a[j] + ".");
                break;
            }

            System.out.print(a[j] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly why you should avoid using magic numbers. Let Java tell the loop when to stop by using the array's length field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the size of the `int[]`.

Your while loop is constantly checking if `a[i]` is less than `4000000` while the `i` variable  is already one index ahead. Each loop will have `a[i] == 0`.

This change will fix the code for you:

```
int i=1;
while(a[i]<=4000000){
    i++;
    a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
}
```

Comment: @user1606773 On SO we say thank you by accepting an answer :-)

Comment: @user1606773 That's ok. You'll learn all the tricks soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the fact that `i` reaches 1000000 (the size of your array) before `a[i]` reaches the termination condition of your loop. Instead of testing the value of `a[i]` you should use a for loop like this:

```
    for (i=2; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
    }
```

In addition, you should use the type `long` rather than int for the items of `a` because the values are getting so large that they overflow the int type and wrap around to negative values, eg:

```
1872856136
1063031469
-1359079691
-296048222
-1655127913
-1951176135
688663248
```

Edit: in fact, using an array with 1000000 elements even a `long` won't be big enough - if you really need values this big you would have to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: That is not the problem at all. Try changing his `while(a[i]<=4000000)` to your `for (i=2; i<a.length; i++)` and you will see that it does not work either.

Comment: I just ran it and it seems fine - obviously you no longer need the i++ inside the loop when using a for, have updated code above.

Comment: @maba why do you think the problem is not with that while loop? This answer is meant for fixing that index out of bounds  exception but not to help the user with the logic

Comment: @srikanthyaradla OK but it seems that he wants to stop when the value of `a[i]` is less than `4000000`. He is not trying to fill the `int[]`. This example continues too long.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `a` contains 1,000,000 elements, starting from zero.  When you loop through them here:

```
while(a[i]<=4000000)
```

you're exceeding the index capacity.  The first index to exceed the capacity is 1,000,000, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, you increment i before checking if you're done. Whenever that condition gets evaluated, it gets evaluated on the element *you're about to calculate* - but there's nothing there yet.

This means your while loop never terminates - and eventually, `i` becomes 1,000,000, at which point `a[i]` can no longer be evaluated, causing this exception to be thrown - because the last element in `a` is `a[999999]`.

You can fix this in a couple of ways; the clearest would be to start `i` at 1, and increment it *before* assigning to `a[i]`.

As an aside, fixed-size arrays are generally a bad choice, and variable-sized lists like `ArrayList<E>` is a better choice - although in this particular case, that would eventually just lead to an OutOfMemoryException instead, due to the logic bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
while(a[i]<=4000000)
```

In your case you can do as

```
while(i < a.length && a[i]<=4000000 ){
    a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
    i++;        
}
```

And your program will work perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra condition 
`while(i < a.length && a[i]<=4000000)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at while loop,look into the condition

```
while(a[i]<=4000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out . You can do like this :

```
 int i=2;
for(;i<a.length && a[i]<=4000000;i++)
{
     a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];

}
```

It checks that the value is less than 400000 and the index should be less than 100000.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] a = new int[40000000];
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Two Numbers From Which You Want To Start Fibonacci Sequence.");
        a[0] = b.nextInt();
        a[1] = b.nextInt();
        for(int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
            a[i] = (a[i-2] + a[i-1]);
        }
        System.out.println("The fibonacci Sequence is: ");
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.println(a[j] + ", ");
            sum += a[j];
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum of the fibonacci sequence: " + sum);
    }

}
```